# How to update columns value with new value

Tags: hibernate

I would like to update column value with a new entity value incrementally, for example:

support I have a table USER with COLUMN name BALANCE

for specific user, his balance is 3000.

Now, I would like to set his value to 3500.

I have hibernate "User" Entity that has a 'balance' value of 500.

How can I make the update??

If I would like to make it using pure sql query, I would simple do:

"UPDATE USER set balance = balance+500 where user_id=3"

I would like to avoid calling sql and use hibernate.

Comment: u can do in hibernate too. "UPDATE USER set balance ="+( balance+500 )"+"where userId=3". OR set values to entity class like user.setBalance(bal+500). session.update(user)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried below code? Always remeber to mention what all possible solutions you tried before asking question.

```
User user=session.get(User.class, 3); // 3 is ID of user. 
user.setBalance((user.getBalance()+500));
session.saveOrUpdate(user);
session.commit();
```

Comment: if that worked accept answer so tha other can fidn it easily.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE User u SET u.balance = :balance WHERE u.id = :userId");
query.setParameter("balance", balance + 500);
query.setParameter("userId", 3);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Please not that you are updaing the `User` entity over HQL, not the `USER` table like you would with SQL. I also assumed that the `balance` and the `id` columns are mapped to the `balance` and the `id` attributes in the `User` entity.

Comment: I cannot do:
query.setParameter("balance", balance + 500);
because I don't have "balance", this value should come from DB.
All I have is the 500 which I would like to add to the existing value (3000) in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using JPA in the following way:

```
CriteriaUpdate<User> criteria = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(User.class);
Root<User> user = criteria.from(User.class);
criteria.set(user.<Integer>get("balance"), builder.sum(user.<Integer>get("balance"), 500));
criteria.where(builder.equal(user.get("user_id"), 3));
entityManager.createQuery(criteria).executeUpdate();
```

It will execute following query on database:

```
UPDATE user SET balance = balance + 500 WHERE user_id = 3
```

If you want to do it using Hibernate then i will advice you to use locking as  using Hibernate you will first select the row, update the balance in Application and then update the row. In between select and update statements if row gets updated with different balance then you will end up writing incorrect data into the database. So, you can use following code to avoid it:

```
User user = session.get(User.class, 3, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
user.setBalance(user.getBalance() + 500);
session.saveOrUpdate(user);
```

It will execute following queries on database:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = 3 FOR UPDATE #Let's assume current balance is 3000
UPDATE user SET balance = 3500 WHERE user_id=3
```